# Remove repeated elements from a column in r

Tags: r

Considering the following example vector (class is numeric):

```
dates <- data.frame(A = c(2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025), B = "something")
```

I want to remove any of the daes that are repeated:

```
dates <- data.frame(A = c(2021, 2022, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2023, 
NA, NA, NA, 2024, 2025, NA, NA, NA), B = "something")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can implement akrun's solution with `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
dates %>% 
  mutate(A = replace(A, duplicated(A), NA))
```

```
  A         B
1  2021 something
2  2022 something
3    NA something
4    NA something
5    NA something
6    NA something
7    NA something
8    NA something
9    NA something
10 2023 something
11   NA something
12   NA something
13   NA something
14 2024 something
15 2025 something
16   NA something
17   NA something
18   NA something
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `duplicated`

```
dates$A <- replace(dates$A, duplicated(dates$A), NA)
```

Or update the original object

```
dates$A[duplicated(dates$A)] <- NA
```

---

if these are based on adjacent values, use `rle`

```
dates$A <- replace(dates$A, duplicated(with(rle(dates$A), 
     rep(seq_along(values), lengths))), NA)
```

---

If we want to remove the rows

```
subset(dates, !duplicated(A))
```

Comment: This belongs to a datafrme,, but i only want the dublicate to apply to one column of the dataframe. I was trying to use `mutate`

Comment: @MaralDorri with the current code, you can do `df1$dates[duplicated(df1$dates)] <- NA`